# TrueRNG Pseudo GUI Issues - Collision

Tags: batch, gui, random-number-generator

I am trying to create a Pseudo GUI for the TrueRNG Hardware using RNGCapture.exe and a custom Batch Based Menu. The RNGCapture program is only command line and a Royal Pain to create Multiple Entropy FIles in Succession.

My Script is able to loop to many predefined counts and file sizes to accomodate a large number of user needs, as well as allow you to enter custom parameters to create a custom loop with user chosen file sizes and file counts.

My issue is i am experiencing Collision on account of using %Random% as a file name placeholder.

The script fires without issue other than the Collision i have described but also the file count is not 10 but 9, this is consistent across multiple tests.

I would like to implement a custom variable to introduce a random string of letters into the filename to eliminate my issue, how do i go about this?

THIS IS NOT A SCHOOL PROJECT, THIS IS PERSONAL!
I Have done 95% of the legwork myself. If needed i can post the entire script but i would prefer not to until it's finished as i want to put it on my Blog and Linkedin

```
@echo off
:start3
set /a var+=1
if %var% EQU 10 goto end3
rngcapture.exe %ChosenComm% C:\rngcapture\10Files20MB\%RANDOM%%RANDOM%%RANDOM% 20971520
goto start3
:end3
echo var has reached %var%.
pause
GOTO MainMenu
```

Comment: Your file count is 9 instead of 10 because you start by incrementing `var` (so it is now 1, not 0) and on it being 10 you exit the loop. As a result the 10th run will never happen. You need to move the `If equ 10` after the `rngcapture` line.

Comment: I made the adjustments you Suggested and am trying a test run now, thx!

Comment: https://github.com/Heckjd1986/TrueRNGMenu

Answer (score 0):

Mokubai is correct, the revised script works as follows...

```
@echo off
:start3
set /a var+=1
rngcapture.exe %ChosenComm% C:\rngcapture\10Files20MB\%RANDOM%%RANDOM%%RANDOM% 20971520
if %var% EQU 10 goto end3
goto start3
:end3
echo var has reached %var%.
pause
GOTO MainMenu
```

Comment: https://github.com/Heckjd1986/TrueRNGMenu